# adding a column with TRUE/FALSE and showing that as a checkbox

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a column with `TRUE` or `FALSE` values

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$Favorite <- "FALSE"
```

I am interested in displaying this column (Favorite) as a checkbox on shiny.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    h2('The mtcars data'),
    dataTableOutput('mytable')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    })
  }
))
```

Source : http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html

Not sure how to make it work, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This may help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/shinyInput$20datatable/shiny-discuss/FeqU0AoTpz0/Zooap7iCIu8J

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT) # dev from github
runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    h2('The mtcars data'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'),
    h2("Selected"),
    tableOutput("checked")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    # helper function for making checkbox
    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) { 
      inputs = character(len) 
      for (i in seq_len(len)) { 
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...)) 
      } 
      inputs 
    } 
    # datatable with checkbox
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
      data.frame(mtcars,Favorite=shinyInput(checkboxInput,nrow(mtcars),"cbox_"))
    }, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, options = list( 
      paging=FALSE,
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { 
Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'), 
      drawCallback = JS('function() { 
Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ') 
    ) )
    # helper function for reading checkbox
    shinyValue = function(id, len) { 
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) { 
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]] 
        if (is.null(value)) NA else value 
      })) 
    } 
    # output read checkboxes
    output$checked <- renderTable({
      data.frame(selected=shinyValue("cbox_",nrow(mtcars)))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: thats it, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Carl

Comment: great solution. is there also an option to skip the checkbox for certain row based on values of other rows?