# Update plot from interactive table in html

Tags: css, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

What I would like to be able to do is to **update the plot based on the output from the (DT-)table after filtering in the html**.

For example - here is a screenshot of the table filtered for `maz` in the html:

[image]

**I would like the scatter plot to update to only show the values shown in the filtered table.**

Is this possible? I know I could achieve something like this using a [shiny web app](https://www.shinyapps.io), but is it possible to embed some shiny code into the html to achieve this? (I have very limited experience using shiny/html so would be grateful for any pointers/ideas).

I am using R-markdown (and [here is a link to the html produced](http://www.filedropper.com/testnb)):

````
---
title: "Filter interative plots from table results"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %e, %Y')`"
output:
  html_notebook:
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: true
    df_print: paged
  html_document: 
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: true
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, cache=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(stringr)
data(mtcars)
```


# Clean data
## Car names and models are now a string: "brand_model" in column 'car'

```{r include=FALSE}
mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$car <- stringr::str_replace(mtcars$car, ' ', '_')
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
```

# Interactive table using DT

```{r rows.print=10}
DT::datatable(mtcars,
              filter = list(position = "top"),
              selection="none",                 #turn off row selection
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=2)),
                             searchHighlight=TRUE,
                             pagingType= "simple",
                             pageLength = 10,                  #default length of the above options
                             server = TRUE,                     #enable server side processing for better performance
                             processing = FALSE)) %>% 
              formatStyle(columns = 'qsec',
                background = styleColorBar(range(mtcars$qsec), 'lightblue'),
                backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

# Plot disp against mpg using plotly

```{r fig.width=8, fig.height=8}
p <- plot_ly(data = mtcars,
             x = ~disp,
             y = ~mpg,
             type = 'scatter',
             mode = 'markers',
             text = ~paste("Car: ", car, "\n",
                           "Mpg: ", mpg, "\n"),
             color = ~mpg,
             colors = "Spectral",
             size = ~-disp
)
p
```
````

Comment: (p.s. If anyone has any recommendations for how I can best share the .Rmd and .html files to enable better understanding of the problem I would love to hear them!)

Comment: Sadly it can't be done directly. The issue is that DT - filters do not translate into shiny. But you can filter using shiny. will upload my version in an hour.

Comment: @5th - that would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: Okay my firewall here is blocking me. That will have to wait until I'm home.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong and you can do it directly. I changed your code and uploaded it below as an answer. Seems easier that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to my first assessment, it is actually possible. There are multiple additions to your code. I will go through them chronologically:

1. You need to add `runtime: shiny` in the yaml-header to start shiny in any R-markdown file
2. Optional: I added some css style in case you need to adjust your shiny application to fit into certain screen sizes
3. Shiny-documents contain an UI-part, where you configure the user interface. Usually you just use a `fluidPage` function for that
4. The next part is the `server.r`-part where the interesting stuff happens:

   - We assign, i.e., your `DT::datatable` to an `output`-object (usually a list)
   - For each assignment we need to set a `shinyID` which we configure in `ui.r` and then add, i.e, `output$mytable`
   - I added an `element` which shows which rows are selected for debugging
   - The heart of all the changes is `input$mytable_rows_all`. All the controls we set up in the `ui.r` can be called inside the `render`-functions. In this particular case `mytable` refers to the `shinyID` I set for the `DT::datatable` in the UI-part and `rows_all` tells shiny to take all the rownumbers inside the shown table.
   - That way we just subset the data using `mtcars[input$mytable_rows_all,]`

To learn shiny I recommend [Rstudio's tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). After learning and forgetting everything again I advise you to use the [wonderful cheatsheet provided by Rstudio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/images/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf)

The whole modified code looks like this:

````
---
title: "Filter interative plots from table results"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %e, %Y')`"
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document: 
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: true
    df_print: paged
  html_notebook:
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: true
    df_print: paged
---

<style>
 body .main-container {
    max-width: 1600px !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE, cache=TRUE}
library(stringr)
data(mtcars)
```


# Clean data
## Car names and models are now a string: "brand_model" in column 'car'

```{r include=FALSE}
mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$car <- stringr::str_replace(mtcars$car, ' ', '_')
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
```



# Plot disp against mpg using plotly

```{r}
library(plotly)
library(DT)

## ui.r
motor_attributes=c('Cylinder(  shape): V4','Cylinder(  shape): V6','Cylinder(  shape): V8','Cylinder(  shape): 4,Straight Line','Cylinder(  shape): 6,Straight Line','Cylinder(  shape): 8,Straight Line','Transmission: manual','Transmission: automatic')

fluidPage(# selectizeInput('cyl','Motor characteristics:',motor_attributes,multiple=TRUE,width='600px'),
          downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download'),
          DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'),
          plotlyOutput("myscatter"),
          htmlOutput('Selected_ids'))


### server.r
output$mytable<-DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(mtcars,
              filter = list(position = "top"),
              selection='none', #list(target='row',selected=1:nrow(mtcars)),                 #turn off row selection
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=2)),
                             searchHighlight=TRUE,
                             pagingType= "simple",
                             pageLength = 10,                  #default length of the above options
                             server = TRUE,                     #enable server side processing for better performance
                          processing = FALSE))   %>% 
              formatStyle(columns = 'qsec',
                background = styleColorBar(range(mtcars$qsec), 'lightblue'),
                backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                backgroundPosition = 'center')
})


output$Selected_ids<-renderText({
  if(length(input$mytable_rows_all)<1){
      return()
  }

  selected_rows<-as.numeric(input$mytable_rows_all)  
  paste('<b> #Cars Selected: </b>',length(selected_rows),'</br> <b> Cars Selected: </b>',
        paste(paste('<li>',rownames(mtcars)[selected_rows],'</li>'),collapse = ' '))

})

output$myscatter<-renderPlotly({
  selected_rows<-as.numeric(input$mytable_rows_all)  
  subdata<-mtcars[selected_rows,]
  p <- plot_ly(data = subdata,
             x = ~disp,
             y = ~mpg,
             type = 'scatter',
             mode = 'markers',
             text = ~paste("Car: ", car, "\n",
                           "Mpg: ", mpg, "\n"),
             color = ~mpg,
             colors = "Spectral",
             size = ~-disp
)
p
})
```
````

Comment: This is incredibly useful - thanks. When I run this code it fails with `Error in output$myscatter <- renderPlotly({ : object 'output' not found`. Should `ui.R` and `server.R` be saved to separate files?

Comment: For me it works. You can try saving the chunk starting from the `fluidPage`-function into an app.r and load it. However then you need assign the output from `fluidPage` to an object named `ui` and for server-part you need to wrap you code into the brackets of this thing: `server <- function(input, output) { }`. You also need `shinyApp(ui,server)` to call everything. Best you check out the basic shiny-tutorial - takes only ten minutes.

Comment: to deploy that `app.r` try using the `shinyAppDir`-function. You can also try whether for your R-version adding the server and ui functions work