# R Shiny extract values from numericInput Datatable column

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

This is a continuation of my previous question where I needed to integrate shiny inputs into a datatable ([Render numericInputs in a datatable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046641/render-numericinputs-in-a-datatable-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I have a column of numericInputs but I cannot retrieve the values input by a user. I've tried both input$bin_values and shinyValue(input$bin_values, ncol(it_matrix) but it doesn't make a difference. I've also tried to incorporate code to handle some JS callback options ([R Shiny selectedInput inside renderDataTable cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020600/r-shiny-selectedinput-inside-renderdatatable-cells/40027726#40027726)) but that still gets me the same problem where the shiny input variable is empty. What am I missing?

My end-goal here is to take selected rows on the interface_table and only perform a calculation on those columns (row and column index being the same), then output that as a new table. This is a simplified version of that code to just find out how to recover the column of numericInput values the user enters before they press Apply.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(mtcars)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('interface_table'),
    br(),
    actionButton("do", "Apply"),
    br(),
    hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("contents", DT::dataTableOutput('contents')),
      tabPanel("it_contents", DT::dataTableOutput('it_contents'))
    ),
    br()

  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(
      {mtcars}, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                               scrollX = TRUE, dom = 't', ordering = FALSE),
      rownames = TRUE, selection = 'none')


    # helper function for making input number values
    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- numeric(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    # helper function for reading numeric inputs
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value <- input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) NA else value
      }))
    }

    it_matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(names(mtcars)), ncol = 2)
    rownames(it_matrix) <- names(mtcars)
    colnames(it_matrix) <- c("Ordinality","Number of bins")
    it_matrix[,1] <- lengths(lapply(mtcars, unique))

    it_matrix[,2] <- shinyInput(numericInput, ncol(mtcars),
                                "bin_values", value = NULL,
                                width = '100%', min = 0, max = 12)

    output$interface_table <- DT::renderDataTable(it_matrix,
                                                  rownames = TRUE,
                                                  escape = FALSE,
                                                  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
                                                                 #scrollY = '400px',
                                                                 dom = 't',
                                                                 ordering = FALSE)
    )

    it_data <- reactive({
      if (input$do > 0) {
        rs <- input$interface_table_rows_selected
        bv <- shinyValue(input$bin_values, nrow(it_matrix))
        dat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(it_matrix), ncol = 2)
        colnames(dat) <- c("Ordinality","Number of bins")
        dat[,1] <- it_matrix[,1]
        dat[,2] <- input$bin_values
        return(dat)
      }
    })

    output$it_contents <- DT::renderDataTable(
      it_data(), options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                                  scrollX = TRUE, dom = 't', ordering = FALSE),
      rownames = TRUE, selection = 'none')
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

UPDATE: Made changes suggested by (MLavoie), now I get a table output but it only contains the first column (ordinality). When I cat bv or input$bin_values it is a list of NA values meaning it has not picked up the numericInput values.

Comment: a couple of mistakes I think. First in **input$submit > 0** I don't see submit describe anywhere else. Second, in **it_data, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,** I think it should be **it_data(), options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,**.

Comment: Ah yes those are simply mistakes that I completely missed, thank you. I made those corrections and now a datatable is displayed. Still not getting the numericInput values, alas.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems there is another mistake in your code. You don't define anywhere **input$interface_table_rows_selected** so it's hard for this **rs <- input$interface_table_rows_selected** to work

Comment: Ah, that is a built-in function of R Shiny / Datatable rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html. It's very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem - well, there were a few. First one must use a data.frame for shiny inputs in a column and it must be reactive. Second, the input variable is accessed by Id, here as 'bin_values' and not input$bin_values.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(mtcars)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('interface_table'),
    br(),
    actionButton("do", "Apply"),
    br(),
    hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("contents", DT::dataTableOutput('contents')),
      tabPanel("it_contents", DT::dataTableOutput('it_contents'))
    ),
    br()    
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(
      {mtcars}, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                               scrollX = TRUE, dom = 't', ordering = FALSE),
      rownames = TRUE, selection = 'none')


    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- numeric(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value <- input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) NA else value
      }))
    }

    init_ordinality <- lengths(lapply(mtcars, unique))

    it_df <- reactive({
      data.frame(
        Ordinality = init_ordinality,
        Bins = shinyInput(numericInput, ncol(mtcars),
                          'bin_values', value = NULL,
                          width = '100%', min = 0, max = 12),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    })

    output$interface_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      it_df(), rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, options = list(
        autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, #scrollY = '400px',
        dom = 't', ordering = FALSE,
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
    )

    it_data <- reactive({
      if (input$do > 0) {
        dat <- data.frame(
          Ordinality = init_ordinality,
          Bins = shinyValue('bin_values', ncol(mtcars))
        )
        return(dat)
      }
      else { return() }
    })

    output$it_contents <- DT::renderDataTable(
      it_data(),
      options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, dom = 't', ordering = FALSE),
      rownames = TRUE, selection = 'none')
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```